# Safe to enable compression C:\WINDOWS\system32\LogFiles

Tags: iis, log-files

Will it slow down my website if I enable compression on the **C:\WINDOWS\system32\LogFiles** directory?  These files are slowly but surely chewing away drive space and I'd like to slow the expansion.  I'm worried however that this will also slow my websites.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think enabling compression on that folder would affect performance noticeably (logging doesn't block requests to websites), but if you're concerned about the logs' effect on free disk space, maybe it would be a good idea to install a script to compress or delete old logs.

Answer (score 1):

We found that [SmarterStats](http://www.smartertools.com/SmarterStats/Features/Web-Log-Analytics-Website-Statistics.aspx) had serious problems reading compressed folders, so maybe something to watch out for.